# Distinguishing between types of deliveries

Tags: single-word-requests

I am currently writing on a document where I would want to distinguish between types of deliveries rather than just use the general term. The distinction would be made by goods.

First, there are freight deliveries which usually cater to big and bulky crates, require the use of tools to move the freight around, and usually concern either large equipment or a multitude of boxed units. Then there are your typical parcel or document deliveries that courier services deliver. I would even go as far and include food deliveries in this category.

How could I express these differences in my document without explaining it? I considered qualifying delivery by using "large-scale" and "small-scale" but that doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: Freight vs Parcel

Comment: Don't forget baby deliveries. They're usually easier to tell apart from the other two, of course.

Comment: Just when I think I've nailed it shut ... along comes my nemesis, @Janus Bahs Jacquet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Freight versus Parcel deliveries**

> Less than truckload shipping (LTL) is the transportation of relatively small freight. ***The alternatives to LTL carriers are parcel carriers or full truckload carriers***. Parcel carriers usually handle small packages and freight that can be broken down into units less than 150 pounds (68 kg).
>
> See, Wikipedia [**Less than truckload shipping**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_than_truckload_shipping)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/231864/98955) where there is no interference from how the contents are divided, but *in bulk* vs. *retail* might also be useful:

> — [**in bulk**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bulk)
>  1 :  not divided into parts or packaged in
>   separate units
>  2 :  in large quantities
>
> [Full Definition of RETAIL](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retail)
>  : the sale of commodities or goods
>   in small quantities to ultimate consumers; also :  the industry of
>   such selling
>
> [ *Merriam-Webster online* ]